# Get DataFrame column as list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the columns of a pandas `DataFrame` as a list of values.

I can access the first column using `iloc`:

```
df.ix[:,[0]].values
```

However, that returns an array of lists:

```
>>> df3.ix[:,[1]].values
array([[  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
```

How can I return a list of numbers?

I can get what I want by calling the column by name and using `tolist()`:

```
>>> df3['D-328'].tolist()
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0,
```

However, when calling the column by index, that method is not available:

```
>>> df3.ix[:,[0]].tolist()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Comment: Nope: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Comment: Or `df.ix[:, 0].tolist()`

Comment: @jezrael - that's the answer, thanks!

Comment: Aside: if you're only doing selection by position, `.iloc` is preferred to `ix` (whose behaviour is hard to explain).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can try [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) this way:

```
df.ix[:, 0].tolist()
```

And as mentioned [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747137/get-dataframe-column-as-list-of-values#comment59167832_35747137) in comments, you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) this way, if you need select first column by position:

```
df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
```